# My angular chunk is not working in my MVC project

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('abc', function ($scope) {
            $scope.SomeId = "gsdfgsf";
        });
```

```html
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="abc">
<div id="someid" ng-model="SomeId">Abc</div>
{{SomeId}}{{1+2}}
```

Hi I want to use angular in my project to keep data of some partial views in one cache place. But when I started working on this I found that the code, in above snippet, was working on sample project is no more working with my Project. It works fine on my layout page but do not good with my partial view page.

I have tried the following as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    debugger;
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('abc', function ($scope) {
        debugger;
        $scope.SomeId = "some id";
    });
</script>
```

Then in `HTML` I used `ng-app = "myApp"` in main `div` and then `ng-controller = "abc"` and `ng-model = "SomeId"` in input tag. I then tried to show `{{SomeId}}` or even simple expression like `{{1+2}}` and nothing is working. On debugging I came to know that the first `debugger` got the break but second one is not. Also browser is not showing any error.
Kindly help me the way out.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the `]` wrongly. Change it like this

```js
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('abc', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        debugger;
        $scope.SomeId = "some id";
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="abc">
{{SomeId}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is showing me `angular is not defined` error.

Comment: Have you included the reference for angular in your script tags?

Comment: it is working in sample project but my question here is what could be the conflict that it is not working in my main project's partial views. It is also working on layout page as well.

Comment: The above snippet you posted have the error I mentioned in my answer. Maybe you can show your index html

Comment: I added the code above is working fine on sample and layout page but in partial view the same one is not working.

Comment: What are using for partial view.Are you getting any errors and have u included ng-view or ui-view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150263/discussion-between-ammar-and-vivz).

Comment: I am using MVC and opening Partial Views by `@ActionLink()` I want angular in my partial view.

Comment: I don't know if you can open partial views  by @ActionLink(). I am only familiar with ng-view and ui-view routing for partial views.